# Slick - How to insert into table with no primaryKeys

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table with no primary keys. How can I insert data into it. When I have a table with primary key I can do `insertOrUpdate(...)` but I don't see a method for just inserting.

This is what I do for tables with primary keys:

```
db.run(table.insertOrUpdate(colorEntity))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resort to using `+=` to insert a row:

```
db.run(table += colorEntity)
```

To insert multiple rows in a batch, use `++=`:

```
val colorEntities: Seq[Color] = Seq(...)
db.run(table ++= colorEntities)
```